# C# serial port data received event handler is being triggered twice

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am receiving 6 bytes array data in `C#` visual studio 2010 windows forms applications using data received event handler.

But when i try to show this data on my form label it shows repetition of 6 byte data when i need only 6 bytes.

Can you please tell me how does serial port received event works?

Comment: See line 127, you don't check how many bytes you have actually received :)

Comment: Could you share your code? It may be that there is something wrong there. As I recall I did not have such issues with serial port data

Comment: @Pako Actually when i Did debugging on my code i came to know  Serialport data received handler is called twice for single data received event. But Now i have used another array to hold data that solved my problem .. Thank you so much